# Accessign Local Sql Ce with a Local Wcf Service

Tags: c#, wcf, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I am using Sync Framework in SL App to sync Sql Server and local SqlCe DB.

Having problem in connecting to Sqlce. Getting an Exception here

new SqlCeConnection("http://localhost/Sample.sdf");

Error:
ArgumentException was unhandled by user code.
The connection object is not valid. Cannot create a new instance of the connection object."

Thanks

Comment: do you mind posting your code?

Comment: static string localCon = @"Data Source= '../Sample.sdf'"; static string remoteCon = "Data Source= XXX;Initial Catalog=DB"; SqlCeSyncProvider provider = new SqlCeSyncProvider();
            provider.ScopeName = scopeName;
            provider.Connection = new SqlCeConnection(localCon); When i try to connect SqlCe its breaking @ runtime i tried to give different Paths but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use a local file path, not an http path for the data source

Comment: Thanks Erik, You are right. The Main problem for Error is SQL Server Compact is not intended for ASP.NET development.    Used a turn Around by using following code  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("SQLServerCompactEditionUnderWebHosting", true); .

Comment: I am having a similar problem.  I am able to open the connection to my SQL Server Compact database without any trouble (it is a local file using a local path), but when I try to add the connection to a sync provider, it gives this error.  Any ideas?